# How do I use comprehension to make a list of values from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

```
{'AAPL': (175.96, 'Apple Inc'),
 'GOOGL': (0.00475, 'Alphabet Inc'),
 'TVIX': (0.0045, 'Credit Suisse AG')}
```

How I can extract a list of: `Apple In`, `Alphabet Inc`, and `Credit Suisse AG`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this list comprehension:

```
print([i[1] for i in yourdictionary.values()])
```

Output:

```
['Apple Inc', 'Alphabet Inc', 'Credit Suisse AG']
```

*P.S. Change `yourdictionary` to the actual name of your dictionary.*

Answer (score 3):

```
l={'AAPL': (175.96, 'Apple Inc'), 'GOOGL': (0.00475, 'Alphabet Inc'),
'TVIX': (0.0045, 'Credit Suisse AG')} 
out=[]  
for k,v in l.items():
     make_list=list(v)
     out.append(make_list[1])
print(out)
```

I hope it work for you

Comment: `make_list=list(v)` is completly unecessary. Just `out.append(v[1])` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Could also use tuple unpacking to select the second item from each tuple:

```
>>> d = {'AAPL': (175.96, 'Apple Inc'),
...  'GOOGL': (0.00475, 'Alphabet Inc'),
...  'TVIX': (0.0045, 'Credit Suisse AG')}
>>> [y for _, y in d.values()]
['Apple Inc', 'Alphabet Inc', 'Credit Suisse AG']
```

Or even a functional approach using [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list(map(itemgetter(1), d.values()))
['Apple Inc', 'Alphabet Inc', 'Credit Suisse AG']
```